# How to show that the sequence $ \left\lbrace 4+3(-1)^n \right\rbrace $ diverges by $ \varepsilon -N $ definition?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

**Preface**

We will use the following facts

i) The sequence $ \left\lbrace a_n \right\rbrace $ is convergent to $a$ if for each $ \varepsilon >0$ there exists $ N>0 $ such that $ \vert a_n -a \vert < \varepsilon $ whenever $ n>N$.

(ii) $ |A+B| \leqslant |A|+|B| $; and $ \vert -A+B \vert = \vert A-B \vert $

(iii) $ (-1)^{2n+1} =-1$ and $ (-1)^{2n}=1 $

(iv) The statement $ 8<8 $ is a contradiction. Contradiction=false in every way.

**Proof**

Suppose the sequence is convergent to $ \omega $. Then for each $ \varepsilon >0 $, there exists $ N>0 $, such that $ \vert 4+3(-1)^n - \omega \vert < \varepsilon $, whenever $ n>N $. When $ n $ is even, we have $ \vert 7-\omega \vert < \varepsilon $, whenever $ n>N $. When $ n $ is odd, we have $ \vert 1-\omega \vert < \varepsilon $, whenever $ n> N $. We choose $ \varepsilon=1 $ and  consider \begin{align*}
 8 &=\vert 7+1 \vert=\vert 7 -\omega + \omega +1\vert\\
  &=\vert (7-\omega)+4 -3+\omega \vert \\
  & \leqslant \vert 7 -\omega \vert + \vert 4 \vert+ \vert -3+\omega \vert \\
  &= \vert 7 -\omega \vert + \vert 4 \vert+ \vert -2 -1+\omega \vert \\
  & \leqslant \vert 7 -\omega \vert + \vert 4 \vert+\vert -2 \vert + \vert -1+\omega \vert \\
  &= \vert 7 -\omega \vert + 6 + \vert 1-\omega \vert \\
  & < 2 \varepsilon +6 \\
  &= 8
 \end{align*}
This is a contradiction.

Question: Do you like this proof? Is it correct?

Comment: It is strange that $\epsilon=3$ should be good enough to show the desired result, but your method would not work. Apparently, you are somewhat wasteful in how you use the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Riquelme No, you do choose an $\varepsilon$. The contrapositive of "for all $\varepsilon$, there exists an $N$ such that..." is "there exists a $\varepsilon$ such that for all $N$..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks good through choosing $\varepsilon=1$. Once you have done this, you have that $$|7-\omega|<1\text{ and }|1-\omega|<1.$$
The first inequality has a solution set of $6<\omega<8$ and the second has a solution set of $0<w<2$. No real need for the extended calculation when you can simply solve for $\omega$ and show no solution exists.

Edit: Technically, after you choose $\varepsilon=1$, you should say something like "Now, let $N$ be arbitrary." Then any even $n>N$ gives us $|7-\omega|<1$ and any odd $n>N$ gives us $|1-\omega|<1$. This shows super clearly what your logic is showing.

Comment: That is shorter version. Like showing that we cannot get two limits for one sequence. Is it what you mean?

Comment: More like: If there is a limit, what is it? It's close to 7 and it's close to 1. Uh oh!

Comment: This is something that I did not know. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using your idea a cleaner way to show the contradiction is noticing that

$$
2>|7-w|+|1-w|\geqslant |7-w+w-1|=6
$$